# Color fade over time with kineticjs shapes

Tags: javascript, colors, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I have a simple question about color fade.

I want to have that the one color blends into another color in durtation.
If I use the kineticjs you can use: .transitionTo(). You can set a duration and he will do the action in the duration given.

Sadly it works only for opacity and movement. Color will still be put instantly instead of blending over time.
How can I have still a fade-in with two colors?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

TransitionTo is only used for numeric values, color is not a numeric value, so you can't use transitionTo on it.

To transition colors, you would have to create your own solution.

Try some existing jQuery : http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/ktTD6/

```
jQuery(function($) {

$('#bg-animated').hover(function() {

    $(this).data('bg-original', $(this).css('backgroundColor')).animate({
        backgroundColor: '#FF0000'
    }, 500);

}, function() {

    $(this).animate({
        backgroundColor: $(this).data('bg-original')
    }, 500);

});

});
```

[Background color change transition with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14363220/background-color-change-transition-with-jquery)